# How to enable or disable any button in angular 2 based on mandatory and optional field

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want the my Save button to be enabled when Placeholder value is 'Optional'.When the value is 'Mandatory' the Save button should be disabled and get enabled only if I enter some value for that field.

My template-

```
<md-input name="" [placeholder]="isOptional()"></md-input>
<input type="button" disabled="placeholder==='Mandatory'" value="Save">
```

In my typescript file-

```
isOptional(){
if (cond1|| cond2){
 return 'Mandatory';
}
else if (cond3||cond4){
return 'Optional';
}
```

I am trying something like above in my template but not getting the proper output.Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<md-input name="" #input [placeholder]="isOptional()"></md-input>
<input type="button" disabled="input.placeholder === 'Mandatory'" value="Save">
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would like to make a form. You can do that with this:

```
<form
    (ngSubmit)="sendFunction(anyForm)"
    #anyForm="ngForm"
>
    <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="any placeholder"
        required
    />
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!anyForm.form.valid">
        Add Todo
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component:

```
option: string;

isOptional(){
if (cond1|| cond2){
 this.option = 'Mandatory';
}
else if (cond3||cond4){
this.option = 'Optional';
}
```

in the html:

```
<input type="button" [disabled]="option==='Mandatory'" value="Save">
```